# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
Controller:
    @RequestMapping(value="/balance.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView balance_navigation(@ModelAttribute("command") NetBean netBean,BindingResult result){
            System.out.println("controller balance");
            //int bal= netservice.displaybalance(cid);
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            System.out.println("controller Map object balance");
            model.put("balance", netservice.displaybalance(cid));
            System.out.println("controller put() balance");
            return new ModelAndView("balance", model);
Dao:
`@Override
    public int displaybalance(int cid) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println("query before executed in balance");
    Query query=session.createQuery("select accbal from Account as se where se.cid=cid");
    ////select ACCBAL from Account a  join Customer s on a.cid=s.cid where s.cid=cid
    System.out.println("query executed in balance");
    query.setParameter(0,cid);
    return (int) query.list().get(0);`
```

**org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.controller.Netcontroller.balance_navigation(com.bean.NetBean,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode

**

Comment: You should post a more clear example. Your snippet does not appear to be using any Hibernate sessions, nor does it relate to the 400 error you mention in your title. Refer to [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for assistance.

Comment: Please add more code,Where all u have dependency with session and url mapping

Answer (score 0):

replace your @ModelAttribute("command") to @ModelAttribute("netBean")
same thing jsp also ModelAttribute="netBean"

Comment: can any one have springhibernate mvc anootation based sessionmangement type eamle please help me